My Angular 17 project does not run the script
I am creating a menu that changes color when I scroll, when I run the application the script does not run, I am new to Angular and I don't know if I am doing it wrong.
my html index code:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Solticom</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>  
  <script>
    const navEl = document.querySelector('.navbar');

    window.addEventListener ('scroll' , () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 56) {
        navEl.classList.add('navbar-scrolled');
      } else if (window.scrollY <= 56) {
        navEl.classList.remove('navbar-scrolled');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>


my html menu code:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="assets/images/logo_sol_v1.png" width="310" height="auto" class="d-inline-block align-top img-fluid" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" [routerLink]="['/home']" >Inicio </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Servicios
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Experiencia Laboral
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Proyectos relevantes</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Certificaciones</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Galería</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Distribuidores</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mesa de ayuda</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

I realized through another script that I had already used before and that I didn't run either, the AOS library, but by researching I was able to solve it.

you should probably use @HostListener for that event... in your .ts file for the component.  https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener  Ex: @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onWindowScroll() {
if (window.scrollY > 56) {
this.scrolled=true;
} else if (window.scrollY <= 56) {
this.scrolled=false;
}  You can then use [ngClass]="scrolled ? '': 'navbar-scrolled'" in html.  In general you should avoid putting 
As browsermator writes, don't put your DOM manipulation of an Angular component in the index html file. That belongs in the component. Consider this, when you call:
const navEl = document.querySelector('.navbar');

the browser only sees this
<app-root></app-root>

The actual content of the component is yet to be rendered so there is no element with a class of navbar to be selected. If you do the manipulation inside the component, preferably in an OnInit, Angular would have had time to actually create the DOM element you're targeting.
